# How to Use Query Params With WSO2 API Manager 1.8?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using Wso2 API manager 1.8 . I have created one API
    http://example.com:8280/api/test/v1/user/{userId}/content.json , 
    Here userID value Coming dynamically .Normal API call working fine , ie

```
http://example.com:8280/api/test/v1/user  /200/content.json ,I am   
getting the results fine.Now I want to apply pagination. I am passing   
some query-params with this ,ie http://example.com:8280/api/test/v1/user
/200/content.json?startIndex=0&count=1

But 403 forbidden error coming .  
<ams:fault>
     <ams:code>900906</ams:code>
    <ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given 
    request</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /api/streams, version: v3 
     with key: b3672a32d5b152a979cc36cb4de7f9b</ams:description>
```

Why this happening ?.

```
Here is my api xml source code .   
<resource methods="OPTIONS POST GET"
         uri-template="/user/{userId}/content.json"
         faultSequence="fault">
  <inSequence>
```

How can I solve the Problem. Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is your URL does not match with resource pattern.
Check this [post](http://vvratha.blogspot.sg/2015/01/adding-url-parameters-in-wso2-apimanager.html) for a sample

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for reply. I have got the answer for this. Give * at the end of resource i.e. /user/{userId}/content.json* at the time when you create the API. Then it will accecpt anything you give at the end of that (also for nothing).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lucky you had "/content.json" after the path parameter. The URL pattern "/user/{userId}*" will not work for URL /user/200 and /user/200?startIndex=0&count=1. Anyone from WSO2 want to share their comments?