# How to use url-mapping value in wso2 configuration xml

Tags: xml, wso2, url-mapping, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Below is the URL which i am using -

http://localhost:8280/ukAddress/v1/NR12GG/bluemill

i need to get value which is after v1 in the url (i.e NR12GG & bluemill) & use it inside resource tag for further manipulation in configuration xml. Could you please let us know what syntax i need to use to get the value.

```
<api name="admin--Address"
        context="/Address"
        version="v1"
        version-type="url">
      <resource methods="POST GET DELETE OPTIONS PUT"
                url-mapping="/*">

...
..
         </resource>
   </api>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create the api in publisher you can define url-template as

```
/{id1}/{id2}
```

once you define the api using url template you will have the resource element as follow

```
<resource methods="POST GET DELETE OPTIONS PUT"  uri-template="/{id1}/{id2}">
```

then if the request is http://localhost:8280/ukAddress/v1/NR12GG/bluemill

then {uri.var.id1} will give the value NR12GG and {uri.var.id2} will give the value bluemill

1. [WSO2 API Manager v1.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310484/wso2-api-manager-v1-8-0)

Comment: HI Robin, in publisher mode i can see URL Pattern under resources & i have kept it as /* which is reflecting as url-mapping="/*" in configuration xml but where is url-template in publisher mode for configuration. Thanks !

Comment: it is the same place where you need to define the url-template.

Comment: Thanks Robin ! It worked. I have another query in API console my base url will be  http://localhost:8280/ukAddress/v1/ if i want pass  /NR12GG/bluemill as parameter from API console how do i send it. Thanks !